# tomcat: El recurso requerido no está disponible

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse, tomcat

El problema aparece cuando le doy a enviar formulario en `form.jsp`. La acción del formulario es la siguiente, acceder a un controlador:

```
<form class="col s12" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Product_Controller" method="POST">
```

No entiendo por qué si la ruta la he comprobado varias veces y esta bien.¿Por qué podría ser? Lo que más me llama la atención es que ayer si me entraba perfectamente y no he cambiado una sola linea, por eso dudo que el problema sea la especificación de la ruta o como están ordenadas las carpetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**form.jsp**

```html
<body>
    <h4>Rellene el Formulario para Continuar</h4>
    <div class="row form-container">
        <form class="col s12" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Product_Controller" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field ">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">assistant</i>
                    <input id="icon_product" name="nombre" value="${product.name}" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="icon_product">Producto</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field ">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">clear_all</i>
                    <input id="icon_cantidad" name="cantidad" value="${product.quantity}" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="icon_cantidad">Cantidad</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">attach_money</i>
                    <input id="icon_precio" name="precio" value="${product.price}" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="icon_precio">Precio</label>
                </div>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "${producto.id}"/>
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light enviar" type="submit" name="action">Añadir Producto
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Product_Controller.java**

```js
@WebServlet("/Product_Controller")
public class Product_Controller extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
 ProductDAO productDAO = null;
 
 public Product_Controller() {
  productDAO = new ProductDAOImpl();
 }
 
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  String action = request.getParameter("action");
  
  if(action == null) {
   action = "LIST";
  }
  
  switch(action) {
   
   case "LIST":
    listProduct(request, response);
    break;
    
   case "EDIT":
    getSingleProduct(request, response);
    break;
    
   case "DELETE":
    deleteProduct(request, response);
    break;
    
   default:
    listProduct(request, response);
    break;
  }
 }

 
  private void deleteProduct(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   
   String id = request.getParameter("id");
  
   if(productDAO.delete(Integer.parseInt(id))) {
    request.setAttribute("NOTIFICATION", "Product Deleted Successfully!");
   }
   
   listProduct(request, response);
  }
  
  private void getSingleProduct(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
   
   String id = request.getParameter("id");
   
   Product theProduct = productDAO.get(Integer.parseInt(id));
   
   request.setAttribute("product", theProduct);
   
   dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/views/form.jsp");
   
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
  }
  
  private void listProduct(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   
   List<Product> theList = productDAO.get();
   
   request.setAttribute("list", theList);
   
   dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/views/products.jsp");
   
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
  }
  
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   
   String id = request.getParameter("id");
   
   Product product = new Product();
   product.setName(request.getParameter("nombre"));
   product.setQuantity(request.getParameter("cantidad"));
   product.setPrice(request.getParameter("precio"));
   
   if(id.isEmpty() || id == null) {
    
    if(productDAO.save(product)) {
     request.setAttribute("NOTIFICATION", "Product Saved Successfully!");
    }
   
   }else {
    
    product.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    if(productDAO.update(product)) {
     request.setAttribute("NOTIFICATION", "Product Updated Successfully!");
    }
    
   }
   
   listProduct(request, response);
  }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>casoPractico_Javier</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
</web-app>
```

Cualquier ayuda lo agradecería estoy realmente atascado con esto. He probado a hacer un clean, a poner un index.jsp, re-deploy el tomcat, nada ha funcionado de momento.

Comment: Lo de **no he cambiado una sola linea** lo vamos a dejar a parte. Esto no es verdad, algo has cambiado. Comprueba qué te muestra el código fuente de la página para el atributo *action* del formulario. A ver qué valor tiene y luego vemos por donde tirar.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar al final del action, el paramétro que recibe el switch del servlet

action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Product_Controller?action=**LIST**"

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Renegué mucho con esto así que agrego mi aporte
Agregando estas dependencias al pom se resolvió:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.25.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Soy super inexperta, solo comparto lo que lo resolvió en mi caso, pero fueron horas de renegar con esto...